# Are list questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

There are starting to be several questions posted asking for an open list of answers:

- https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/92/have-any-successful-solo-artists-subsquently-formed-joined-successful-bands
- [Have there been musicians who have been in more than one band with a Top-10 hit on different instruments?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/41/have-there-been-musicians-who-have-been-in-more-than-one-band-with-a-top-10-hit)
- https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/157/examples-of-bootleg-releases-that-has-been-more-sucessfull-than-the-original-r

These kinds of questions are almost [universally considered off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki) across the entire StackExchange network. Are they also considered off-topic here?

Comment: Leaving aside the meat of your question, example #1 may be awful for a different reason: "Successful" seems like a recipe for opinion based content as it lacks a reasonable definition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, finite lists are somewhat on topic on SE sites. Infinite lists usually aren't.

In the three specific examples you mentioned, I would say that the second one is on topic. It is a finite list from what I can understand.

The first one, I would classify as off topic, as it is bound to be many solo artists to have form successful bands; and the same is the case in the third example.

Comment: I agree, although I would also note that the *reason* open-ended lists are usually off-topic on Stack Exchange is that they interact very poorly with the answering and voting mechanisms.