# Infinite list questions - still off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

There's a fairly strong "decision" that was made to not have such questions: [Are list questions on-topic?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77/are-list-questions-on-topic)

I wanted to ask:

> What are some DJ-hosted radio stations, available worldwide, that are suitable for discovering new alternative pop and rock music?

But that's an infinite list question. What do people reckon? Definitely off-topic?

There have been rumblings recently that we want to expand beyond the endless identify-this-* questions... so, just asking!

Comment: related: http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/256/should-we-re-open-the-spotify-blacklist-question

Answer (score 4):

Please don't ask these questions as it doesn't make sense for a QA site. The whole point of a QA is that you can look up questions and get answers. This will just be a blob of information that is not a question nor answer so the current system we have doesn't makes sense. While resources are important, this is not the way to do it on SE sites as I've seen many in good intentions fail for many reasons (like the [guitar effects wiki](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/glossary-of-guitar-effects) which shows problems with quality across items, voting on identically important items doesn't show anything, and is still missing items):

1. It will never be complete. You'll always be able to find more resources.
2. It will require a ton of maintenance that we won't be able to keep up with. New resources will be added, old ones will go away.
3. Even if we can maintain it correctly, it will grow to an unwieldy size and not be useful because it is too open ended.
4. It will attract spam entries. Let's say I'm an DJ and I see this list. I have a station so what's stopping me from adding my station as a resource?

There are other problems with this specif question as well as you'll find people take descriptions as "new alternative pop and rock music" music very differently as well (for example is Elle King in your scope? Some alternative pop stations would say yes and others say no). If we really care about a resource we can curate a supported list on the meta, but this isn't going to be useful on the main site due to the reasons stated above.

Comment: Why the downvote *on the question*, if I may ask?

Comment: @topomorto because I completely disagree with trying to get them on-topic which is how the post reads to me. Downvotes on meta are more agree/disagree than votes handled on the main site due to the nature of the meta.

Comment: the post is worded as a question, and very softly with phrasing like "What do people reckon?" and "just asking!". If I had titled it "I think infinite list questions should be on-topic, and here's why", then I would interpret a downvote as a disagreement with that statement and reasoning. But downvoting a question just seems rather unfriendly TBH.

Comment: @topomorto voting has nothing to do with friendliness/unfriendliness so please don't take it that way. Your last sentence in your post also frames it in a way where you are asking for them to be on-topic: "I know some might say "list questions aren't the SE way", but there are some great lists of resources on other sites; I think certain list questions can work pretty well.".

Comment: That was just a little touch of 'humanity' giving a little more context as to why I was asking the question. I've removed it for clarity - the question is meant as a question.