# List request for Vengerov's imagery - on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Maxim Vengerov is a violinist who is known for coming up with vivid imagery in his masterclasses.  [Here's an example](https://youtube.com/watch?v=Wpp7oxrBUq0), but in almost all the excerpts I've seen on YouTube, he comes up with some analogy/imagery for each piece.

Is asking for a list of all the recorded occurrences of this, and what piece they apply to, on topic?

I'm not sure if this crosses the line to music practice or not (which is off topic), but I don't think it'd be on topic on [Music Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com) either.  I've read [this question about list requests](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77/are-list-questions-on-topic), but I'm not sure if this is classed as an infinite list or not.

Comment: I'm not going to fully answer this, but this would definitely not be on topic on the Music Practice and Theory SE as external resource requests are off-topic. Here I'd definitely lean to more off-topic as it encourages incomplete/one off answers that have a good chance of rotting away.